# mysql count rows based on based on result of cont

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to explain this and have no clue which type of sql question i shall use.
I have two querys that i have to combine. The first query count distinct lakes and does some summing.

My other query count data distinct by date, user and lake and outputs how many times the selected user occurs on selected lake

My Querys look like this

1

```
SELECT lakes.*, mycall, sm, mode, SUM(IF(sm != '', 1,0)) AS 'a_lake', COUNT(sm) AS 'total' FROM lakes LEFT JOIN ss_log ON ss_log.sm = lakes.id WHERE mycall = '$ListCall' AND ss_log.sm !='' AND ss_log.sm = lakes.id AND conf = '1' GROUP BY sm ORDER BY a_lake DESC
```

2

```
SELECT DISTINCT mycall, tid, count(distinct date(tid)) as datum, sm FROM ss_log WHERE mycall = '$ListCall' and sm = 'lakes.id'
```

These two Querys work fine separately, but how do i combine these together?
That is, the result of query 1 shall be the input to query 2. The query shall output the same result as the two queries but as a combined result.

Comment: Seeing as both queries are fairly nonsensical, I'd be tempted to start over. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out by my self. Själv är bästa dräng! (As we say in Sweden)

```
SELECT lakes.*, mycall, sm, mode, tid ,count(distinct date(tid)) as visits, SUM(IF(sm != '', 1,0)) AS 'a_lake', COUNT(sm) AS 'total' FROM lakes LEFT JOIN ss_log ON ss_log.sm = lakes.id WHERE mycall = '$ListCall' AND ss_log.sm !='' AND ss_log.sm = lakes.id AND conf = '1' GROUP BY sm ORDER BY a_lake DESC
```